# my nginx cannot load uwsgi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi

trying to run django app "mysite" through uwsgi with nginx on Ubuntu 16.04, but when I start uwsgi and check in my browser, it just hangs.

i set django upstream socket to on port 8002 and nginx to listen on 8003. In the browser i visit 192.168.0.17:8003 prior to running uwsgi and it throws 502 which is expected, so I start uwsgi with

`uwsgi --http :8002 --module mysite.wsgi --logto /tmp/uwsgi.log --master`

and 8003 now hangs when I reload in the browser. I looked through `/var/log/nginx/error.log` but it's blank (so is `access.log`).

Here is nginx config, which is symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf`

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8002; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8003;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 192.168.0.17; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/myusername/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/media;  # your Django     project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/myusername/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/static; # your Django     project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/myusername/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/uwsgi_params; #     the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

I know that Django is running because in my app's `settings.py` I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.17','localhost','127.0.0.1']` and when I visit port 8002 in the browser I get the django "Congratulations!" page. And when I remove 192.168.0.17 from ALLOWED_HOSTS, django still runs on that machine from localhost or 127.0.0.1, so this seems that it must be something to do with how ngnix and uwsgi are talking to each other.

Any ideas??

Comment: What does nginx error log say?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out systemd does not like lines in config files to be too long. I removed a couple long comments in `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service`, restarted uwgsi service and all is well.

I found this out by running `sudo journalctl -u uwsgi` and finding the following error:

```
[/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service:5] Unbalanced quoting, ignoring: "/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown myusername:myusern
```

In researching Unbalanced quoting, found [this git issue](https://github.com/coreos/fleet/issues/992) regarding maximum file line length.